# Disposing of Textures not fully working libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to completely dispose of all Textures in my asset manager and return the memory usage to where it started. I made a very simple test program to try using a static class called AssetManager, fill with 1000 Textures, and then dispose all of them. My goal is to reach the memory usage of where it started. When I run the program I am using 35 megabytes. I then click enter to populate the list and the program reaches roughly 500 megabytes. I then click space to clear and the program then runs at 65 megabytes. Nearly DOUBLE of what I started at! Here is the test AssetManager class called Test

```
    public class Test {

public static Hashtable<String, Texture> textureList = new Hashtable<String, Texture>();

public static void put(String key, Texture texx){
    textureList.put(key, texx);
}

public static Texture getTexture(String key){
    return textureList.get(key);
}

public static void stressTest(int lim){
    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++){
        textureList.put("Texture: " + i, new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")));
    }
}
public static void destroy(String key){
    textureList.remove(key);
}

public static void dispose(){
    for(int i = 0; i < textureList.size(); i++)
        textureList.get("Texture: " + i).dispose();
    textureList.clear();
}

public static int poolSize(){
    return textureList.size();
}
```

}

and here is the rendering method of the main class

```
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
        Test.dispose();
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.ENTER)){
        Test.stressTest(1000);
    }
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    if(Test.poolSize() > 1)
    for(int i = 0; i < Test.poolSize(); i++){
        batch.draw(Test.getTexture("Texture: " + i), i, i, 10, 10);
    }
    batch.end();
```

Any help with this would be huge because my main program is a mining game, which you can imagine is a lot of disposing textures. Also please don't suggest reusing one texture as there are over 1500 *different* textures in my main game.

**Question: ** How do I completely dispose of Textures so that I reach my original memory usage of 35 megabytes

Comment: did u dispose your batch also, i guess sprite batch is your culprit here

Comment: @KumarSaurabh I ran the program and the spritebatch was running as well, then I loaded in everything and then deleted it, so with the spritebatch running it should return to 35

Comment: then u should clear your spritecache because while drawing lot of static things are loaded in sprite batch, try looking into SpriteBatch and SpriteCache class

Comment: I don't see any actual proof that the added 30mb is disposable resource data of any kind. How do you know that what you say is the truth is the actual truth and not just memory used up by "something else" that happens under the hood when using LibGDX/OpenGL?

Comment: I fully agree with you @Gimby. What I asked the OP to do was totaly on my intuition and little bit of experience I had on LIBGDX, Thats why its in comment and not in answer. You are right, Instead of "You should" I should have have used Could, Point taken

Comment: @Gimby I let the program run for 1 minute and task manager reported that it was running at 35 mb I then loaded a lot of textures and the task manager reported 500 mb. I then disposed of all textures and waited 5 minutes and the task manager reported 65 mb. So even after returning to its original state it gained 30 mb. So since we started at 35, we should be able to get back down to 35. Agreed?

Comment: @Gimby Please elaborate, how could I start at 35 and never return? Is there a way to cut down this 65?

Comment: Because something else uses it. Rather than looking at numbers and guessing away blindly, try a profiler and actually see where memory goes. Perhaps you're right, perhaps you're wrong. Measure, don't guess. Until you measure, this question is questionable.